# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{cos(px)-cos(qx)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx$ where $\epsilon,p,q>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

> (a) For $p,q >0$, compute, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{cos(px)-cos(qx)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx,$$ where $\epsilon>0$.
> (b) For $p,q >0$, compute, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{cos(px)-cos(qx)}{x^2}dx.$$
> (c) Is it true that,
> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{cos(px)-cos(qx)}{x^2+\epsilon^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{cos(px)-cos(qx)}{x^2}dx.$$

I have to do this exercise but am a bit stuck. This is what I have so far:

**Complex function:** We want to contour integrate it so first we consider the complex function,
$$f(z) = \frac{cos(pz)-cos(qz)}{z^2 + \epsilon^2}=  \frac{cos(pz)-cos(qz)}{(z + i\epsilon)(z-i\epsilon)}.$$

Note that this has **poles** for $\pm i\epsilon$.

Consider the **contour** $\gamma$ thats equal to $[-R,R]$ and the semi-circle $C_R$ with radius R on the upper plane.
Note that $+i\epsilon$ is a pole in the contour. Using the residue theorem we see,
$$\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = 2\pi i \, \text{Res}_{i\epsilon}f(z).$$

We calculate the **residue**,
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{i\epsilon}f(z) &= \lim_{z \to i\epsilon} (z-i\epsilon)\frac{cos(pz)-cos(qz)}{(z + i\epsilon)(z-i \epsilon)}\\
&=\frac{cos(pi\epsilon)-cos(qi\epsilon)}{2i\epsilon},
\end{align}
I don't know how I can simplify this anymore so just left it like this.

Then we know
$$\oint f(z) dz = \int_{-R}^R f(z)dz + \int{C_R} f(z) dz.$$

So we calculate the **integral over the semi-circle**, we use the parameterisation $z(t) = re^{it}$,
\begin{align}
\int{C_R} f(z) dz &= \int_0^\pi \frac{cos(pz)-cos(qz)}{z^2+\epsilon^2}dz\\
&=\int_0^\pi \frac{cos(pre^{it})-cos(qre^{it})}{re^{2it}+\epsilon^2}rie^{it}dt\\
&=ri \Big[ \int_0^\pi \frac{cos(pre^{it})e^{it}}{re^{2it}+\epsilon^2}dt - \int_0^\pi \frac{cos(qre^{it})e^{it}}{re^{2it}+\epsilon^2}dt \Big].
\end{align}

I am trying to upperbound both of them so that the limit is zero, but I can't get the right answer:
\begin{align}
|ri| \, \Big| \int_0^\pi \frac{cos(pre^{it})e^{it}}{re^{2it}+\epsilon^2}dt \Big| &\leq \pi \, R \, \sup_{z \in C_R}|f(z)|\\
&\leq R \, \Big| \frac{Ri}{R^2+\epsilon^2\Big|}
\end{align}
But in the limit  of $R \to \infty$, I don't get 0.

Can anyone help me out further, do I have the wrong complex function or how am I supposed to get an upperbound for the integral? Can I get a different answer for the residue.

Comment: $\frac{\cos px}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\Re\frac{e^{ipx}}{(x+i\epsilon)(x-i\epsilon)}$, and then close the contour in the upper half-plane.
$\int\frac{\cos px-\cos qx}{x^2}dx=-\int(\cos px-\cos qx)d\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$ - integrate by part first, and you get $-\int\frac{p\sin px-q\sin qx}{x}dx$

Comment: Tip: use `\cos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the analysis in the OP is that $\int_{C_R}\frac{\cos(pz)-\cos(qz)}{z^2}\,dz$ does not vanish as $R\to \infty$.  This is a consequence of the fact that  $$\left|\cos(|a|Re^{i\phi})\right|=\left|\cos(|a|R\cos(\phi))\cosh(|a|R\sin(\phi))-i\sin(|a|R\cos(\phi))\sinh(|a|R\sin(\phi))\right|$$

grows exponentially as $R\to\infty$.

---

To proceed around this issue, we use Euler's identity and write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(px)-\cos(qx)}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ipx}-e^{iqx}}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Next, setting $R>\varepsilon>0$, we examine the contour integral $I$, defined by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_{C} \frac{e^{ipz}-e^{iqz}}{z^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{ipx}-e^{iqx}}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ip R e^{i\phi}}-e^{iq R e^{i\phi}}}{(R e^{i\phi})^2+\varepsilon^2}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag 2
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, the first integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ tends to the Principal Value Integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ while the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ vanishes.

Moreover, the Residue guarantees that

$$I=\pi \left(\frac{e^{-p\varepsilon}-e^{-q\varepsilon}}\varepsilon\right)$$

Therefore, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(px)-\cos(qx)}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx=\pi \left(\frac{e^{-p\varepsilon}-e^{-q\varepsilon}}\varepsilon\right)$$

Interestingly, as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, we see that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(px)-\cos(qx)}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx =\pi (q-p)$$

Comment: I have a couple questions
 - I don't see why $\cos(px)-\cos(qx) = e^{ipx}-e^{iqx}$, I tried with the exponential form of $\cos$ but don't get there.
 - I don't see why the second integral on the right-hand side of (2) vanishes. I tried by using the inequality $|\int_\gamma f(z) dz \leq \sup_{z \in \gamma} |f(z)| \cdot \text{length}(\gamma)$ but yet again it doesn't work or I might have the wrong supremum

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(px)-\cos(qx)}{x^2}\,dx$ is equal to the Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ipx}-e^{iqx}}{x^2}\,dx$ since the the Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(px)-\sin(qx)}{x^2}\,dx$ is zero (note the odd symmetry of the integrand).  As for the vanishing as $R\to \infty$, clearly the numerator of decaying exponential functions is bounded, while the denominator is $O(1/R^2)$.

Comment: Beautiful answer +1

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you, I understand the first part, but am still stuck on the vanishing. Do you use the formula I use? Since |∫()|≤sup∈|()|⋅length() , I have that the length is $\pi R$ and that the sup$|f(z)|$ is $\frac{R}{R^2 + \epsilon^2}, but multiplying that cancels the $R$ and so the limit doesn't approach 0. What is wrong in my calculation and method?

Comment: @fieke_2000 Note the obvious inequality $$\left|\frac{e^{-pR e^{i\phi}}-e^{-qR e^{i\phi}}}
{R^2 e^{i2\phi }+\varepsilon^2} \right|\le \frac{2}{R^2}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused, we have the integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ip R e^{i\phi}}-e^{iq R e^{i\phi}}}{(R e^{i\phi})^2+\varepsilon^2}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi$, thus we have to find an upperbound for
\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{ip R e^{i\phi}}-e^{iq R e^{i\phi}}}{(R e^{i\phi})^2+\varepsilon^2}\,iR e^{i\phi},
\end{equation}
in your inequality the last part $iR e^{i\phi}$ is not included, as well as the formula I use multiplies that by the length, which is $\pi R$, which results in an $R^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: The $R$ that appears in the numerator is precisely the $R$ that contributes to the length.  So, you'll end up witj an upper bound that is $O(1/R)$.  Do you understand better now?

Comment: Isn't the $R$ in the numerator from the substitution $z(t) = R\,e^{i\phi}$ so that $dz = Ri\,e^{i\phi}$?

Comment: @fieke_2000 Yes, that is correct.  And how does one get the "length" of the contour over the semicircle?  Note that $\left|\int_0^\pi (1) iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\le \int_0^\pi R\,d\phi=\pi R=\text{Length}$.  So, the "length" comes from the integration of the differential.  In general $$\left|\int_C f(z)\,dz\right|\le \int_C |f(z)|\,|dz|\le \sup |f|\times \int_C |dz|=\sup |f|\times \text{Length of }\,C$$In our case $|dz|=R\,d\phi$.

Comment: Ohhh okay, I understand. Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.